# Spark error when working with langchain (I am on databricks)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, openai-api, large-language-model

ImportError: Spark is not installed. run `pip install pyspark`.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
File <command-2122371644497407>, line 3
      1 from langchain_experimental.agents.agent_toolkits.spark.base import create_spark_dataframe_agent
----> 3 agent = create_spark_dataframe_agent(llm=OpenAI(temperature=0), df=graphframe, verbose=True)
      4 agent.run('How many rows have premium cuts')

File /local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-64863c5a-c177-4f58-adac-d5e56cd70936/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain_experimental/agents/agent_toolkits/spark/base.py:50, in create_spark_dataframe_agent(llm, df, callback_manager, prefix, suffix, input_variables, verbose, return_intermediate_steps, max_iterations, max_execution_time, early_stopping_method, agent_executor_kwargs, **kwargs)
     47 """Construct a Spark agent from an LLM and dataframe."""
     49 if not _validate_spark_df(df) and not _validate_spark_connect_df(df):
---> 50     raise ImportError("Spark is not installed. run `pip install pyspark`.")
     52 if input_variables is None:
     53     input_variables = ["df", "input", "agent_scratchpad"]

ImportError: Spark is not installed. run `pip install pyspark`.
```

I am on databricks, Pyspark is fully downloaded and everything, in the library for my cluster too.*

Comment: How did you install the library in the cluster?

Comment: Yea I re-installed using Maven, worked fine